# How to raise/lower window via mouse in Cinnamon?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, cinnamon

Compiz has an option to bind a mouse shortcut (eg, `Alt+Button7`) to raise or lower the window under the mouse.

I find this a very useful way to switch windows.

Is there any way to replicate this shortcut on Cinnamon?

There doesn't seem to be any built-in support for mouse-button shortcuts.
The closest I could find (this doesn't actually work) is to set a keyboard shortcut to raise window, then bind that to the mouse using `xbindkeys`:

```
# .xbindkeysrc
# Raise window
"xset r off; xdotool key Super+F1; xset r on;"
  Alt + b:7
```

I verified that they keyboard shortcut works, and `xbindkeys` works for other actions with the same mouse button, but this binding does nothing (it does type a `P` in terminal; not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my mouse modifier was preventing the keyboard shortcut.

Adding `--clearmodifiers` to the `xdotool` command fixes this:

```
# Raise window
"xset r off; xdotool key --clearmodifiers Super+F1; xset r on;"
  Alt + b:7

# Lower window
"xset r off; xdotool key --clearmodifiers Super+Shift+F1; xset r on;"
  Alt + b:6
```